# Spark sql function to get time stamp from date time string

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, timestamp

I am converting sql version of a code to spark-sql (pyspark) one. I need to get time component from a datetime string. In sql, the code used is

`to_char(a.timeclose,''HH24:MI:SS'') as timeclose`

Which function can be used for pyspark?

Input : 1970-01-01 16:37:59

Output: 16:37:59

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this

```
Data :  
+--------+
|datetime|
+--------+
|09:39:20|
+--------+
 df.registertempTable("sample")
 spark.sql("select split(datetime,':')[0] as a from sample").show()

Output :


    +---+
    |  a|
    +---+
    | 09|
    +---+
```

Answer (score 0):

Spark does not have a standalone - `Time` [Datatype](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datatypes.html) that you will be able to utilise

The closest you can use is to convert your current datetime/timestamp to epoch using - [unix_timestamp](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.unix_timestamp.html?highlight=unix#pyspark.sql.functions.unix_timestamp)

Apart from that kindly go through - [Minimalistic Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)  and share examples/samples from your dataset to assist you

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution

SQL Code `to_char(a.timeopen,'HH24:MI:SS') as timeopen`

Alternative for that in pyspark `substring(CAST (a.timeopen AS string ),-8) as timeopen`

Input : 1970-01-01 16:37:59

Output: 16:37:59